# How can I modify/disable Chrome's Emacs keybindings?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Because I am constantly switching between macOS, Linux, and Windows, I have standardized on ctrl-c for copy and ctrl-v for paste.  Overriding it in macOS using System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts works pretty well (except for Java programs), but I have noticed odd behavior in Chrome and Slack: I can't paste in the middle of line.  When I hit ctrl-v in the middle of the line, the cursor jumps to the end of the textbox.  If I hit ctrl-v at the end of the textbox, it will paste.  My assumption is that this is tied to the Emacs keybinding for ctrl-v (page down).  Is there some hidden way to edit these keybindings to clear them?  I am a Vi user and have no desire to use Emacs keybindings let alone let them interfere with my copy and paste keybindings.